# php taking a long time to show results

Tags: php

i have this code and it works properly the only issue is it is taking up to a min and a half to return the values from the external page, im not quite certain what could be causing the issues i mean its working correctly so its clearly not a coding issue at least none that i see, any help would be much appreciated

```
<?php
echo "<style type='text/css'>
html{color:#fff;
font-weight:bold;
}
.btn{
background: url(/runescape/navbar.gif);

border:solid 1px #fff;
color:#fff;

}
.addbar{
background:#333;
color:#fff;

}</style>";

$username = $_REQUEST['lookup'];

$hs = file_get_contents("http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player=".$username);

$hs = explode("\n",$hs);

$skills = array("overall","attack","def","str","hp","range","prayer","magic","cook","wc","fletch","fishing","firemaking","crafting","smithing","mining","herb","agility","steal","slayer","farming","runecrafting","hunter","cons");

$i = 0;



foreach($skills as $value){

$hs[$i] = explode(",",$hs[$i]);



$stats[$value]["level"] = $hs[$i][1];



$i++;
}

echo "<center>";
echo " <form action='/runescape/phpfile/hs.php'>";
echo "<input class='addbar' name='lookup' id='lookup' type='text' />";
echo "<input class='btn' name='submit' type='submit' value='submit' /></form> ";

echo $stats["attack"]["level"];






 ?>
```

issue has been fixed using curl added this script

```
    function curl_file_get_contents($url)
    {
     $curl = curl_init();
     $userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

     curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url); //The URL to fetch. This can also be set when initializing a session with curl_init().
     curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE); //TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.
     curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5); //The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect.  

     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent); //The contents of the "User-Agent: " header to be used in a HTTP request.
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE); //To fail silently if the HTTP code returned is greater than or equal to 400.
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); //To follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part of the HTTP header.
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE); //To automatically set the Referer: field in requests where it follows a Location: redirect.
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); //The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.   

     $contents = curl_exec($curl);
     curl_close($curl);
     return $contents;
    }
```

and changed this from 
    $hs = file_get_contents("http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player=".$username);

to
   $hs =  curl_file_get_contents("http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player=".$username);

Comment: The call to `file_get_contents()` is the likely culprit.

Comment: 119640,2066,94519203 204524,81,2256436 195219,81,2304741 152887,91,5951322 188300,88,4445230 157245,83,2937147 171434,72,970659 200161,84,3181235 85474,99,13221260 182120,84,3144233 57509,99,13212189 116839,85,3546181 62526,99,13195835 80306,82,2656557 72756,85,3545729 74207,86,3928022 134104,75,1247268 122006,73,1031588 114415,73,1095479 142871,76,1436798 81285,80,2100576 106654,78,1761459 60178,85,3372459 128336,74,1132121 125521,75,1257179 130717,77,1587500 -1,1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1

Comment: You should benchmark it and compare it to curl

Comment: thats the content its reading just sets of numbers like that so it really shouldnt be taking even close to that long

Comment: You could use microtime before and after file_get_contents() to see how long it takes

Comment: @freddiey it's not the content that is slowing you down, it's the time it takes for your server to ask runescape.com's server for the information, and for that server to send it back to yours. I suggest trying what John Conde said and investigate how CURL would work for timing on this. Another option is that you load your page as normal and do that API call with AJAX so at least your page would load at normal speed (then you just wait for the spinner while results load)

Comment: @anthonygore did a  micro time and got a result of 30.513604879379
also im not quite sure how to use curl in the least bit

Comment: i have access to the php ini file would there be a way to decrees the time by changing a setting?

Comment: fixed the issue with curl, its near instant now thanks guys